# background image or color breaks on scrolling right

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is a screen shot when browser is minimized and window is not yet scrolled right.
[image]

The gray header bar appears neat, but watch when I scroll right.

[image]

It ends when I scroll right. This has become a night mare on mobile devices.

Here is the css for the #header

```
#header {
    background-color: rgb(227,227,227);
    background-color: rgba(227,227,227,1);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    padding: 27px 0;
}
```

I tried many changes like repeat-x and replacing color with image but nothing works. Can I get an answer for this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
#header{
    background: #E3E3E3;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
    padding: 27px 0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I didn't get you, what actually you want to do? If possible then show the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this full screen CSS technique:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Sorry come again! I did not get that. What are you trying to say? Why the html tag has those properties? And what is the bg.png? I dont have  any image for my background. Its just the plain default white.

Comment: it's just a generic property. Apply it to your required css elements. You said "background image" in your title so this is a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

Swaroop,

Any chance you can paste in the full html code?  It looks like something in a parent element (containing element) is altering the properties of your background.

If #header isn't contained by anything, it will default to a width of whatever is inside of it (which may not be 100%).  So add the 100% property and it will stretch full screen in width.  If it still doesn't stretch across the entire screen, at any time, that means that something surrounding that element is keeping it from expanding.

Thanks Swaroop,

Aaron